# Integrate Flurry Analytics into a MonoTouch app

Tags: mobile, xamarin.ios, flurry

I've installed XCode and MonoTouch and built a basic app.

I'm trying to integrate Flurry Analytics into my application. I signed up and downloaded the SDK but I don't know what to do with it. I think I need a binding library and I found [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings).

Should I clone that repository or is it already installed somewhere because I have MonoDevelop installed? Is there somewhere standard I should clone it to?

I then add a reference from my application to the FlurryAnalytics.dll. Do I need to do anything with the FlurryAnalytics SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to add a reference to FlurryAnalytics.dll in your project, no need to do anything with the SDK you downloaded.

But have in mind that the dll in that git repository might be somewhat out of date, in which case you should rebuild the dll (and in this case you do need the SDK). Here is what you need to do:

- Find libFlurry.a in the SDK and put it in the repository's FlurryAnalytics/binding directory.
- Open a terminal and navigate to the repository's FlurryAnalytics/binding directory.
- Execute `make`.

This should build an updated FlurryAnalytics.dll.

Comment: I am trying this and I get an error after my "make" command. error reading resource libFlurry.a

Comment: Forgot that the version number was on the end of the file