# Creating Flurry analytics dll for Flurry SDK 4.4.0 for integrating with monotouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, flurry

For previous versions I was able to create dll successfully but now I have downloaded latest SDK of Flurry i.e. 4.4.0.

I am creating .dll by following instructions given in below link
[Integrate Flurry Analytics into a MonoTouch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527901/integrate-flurry-analytics-into-a-monotouch-app) but it is giving below error on terminal.

```
Error Section:
 make build DIRS="AdJitsu ATMHud facebook FlurryAnalytics FlurryAppCircle  GebePrinter      GoogleAdMobAds  MGSplitViewController Parse PayPal RedLaser Tapku TestFlight Three20    UrbanAirship"
   for i in AdJitsu ATMHud facebook FlurryAnalytics FlurryAppCircle  GebePrinter   GoogleAdMobAds  MGSplitViewController Parse PayPal RedLaser Tapku TestFlight Three20    UrbanAirship; do (cd $i && make); done
 (cd binding; make)
 It would appear that you do not have a copy of libAdJitsu.a which
 is needed to build the AdJitsu bindings.

 You'll need to obtain a copy of libAdJitsuSDK.a from AdJitsu.com
  make[3]: *** [libAdJitsuSDK.a] Error 1
 make[2]: *** [build-binding] Error 2
 (cd binding; make)
  make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: I've successully integrated a flurry in my project a few days ago with this sample: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/FlurryAnalytics, hope it will help you.

Comment: I had also integrated successfully for previous version but for latest version its giving error while creating dll from binding and latest flurry SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used `make` for all the bindings in to git repo (wrong directory level).

What you should do is the run `make` inside the Flurry directory. That will build only the binding you want - and won't require you to download every requirements for every bound library.